# Exit CodeBuild prematurely with success code

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have a AWS CodeBuild template in a buildspec.yml file with the following line in the build section:

```
- if [ "${STAGE}" = "alpha" ]; then echo "Quitting alpha build." && exit 0; fi
```

My expectation is that the build should exit the build if the $STAGE variable is set to `alpha` with a successful finish. However, it goes to the next line.

If I change the exit code to `1`, the build fails at that point as expected.

Any ideas how to end a build prematurely like this, and is there something obviously wrong with this line?

Answer (score 5):

Imagine your line of code being run in a subshell. The return value is the code of the last command. Whether `test` (`[`) returns non-zero or not, the `if` returns zero, unless you exit with something else. In other words, there is no way to distinguish between `$STAGE` not being `alpha` and `exit 0`. So if you want to terminate prematurely, you must exit with a non-zero code.

Answer (score 5):

> So if you want to terminate prematurely, you must exit with a non-zero
> code.

thanks for that answer, its true exit 0 has NO effects in a buildspec.yml

I had the same situation and was searching hours but this finding here shows also there is **a need for stopping a CodeBuild with BUILD State: SUCCEEDED** otherwise you only prematurely can get BUILD State: FAILED when  exit 1

but unfortunately the FAILED state disturbs the following CodeBuilds in the AWS CodePipeline then, so hopefully AWS can offer a "prematurely SUCCEEDED exit" in future, would be helpful in my case too